# Android - invalidate() in onDraw()

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-image

I created two class - one is a class which extends `SurfaceView` and has a method `onDraw()`, inside which I'm drawing an image on my canvas:

```
public class Board extends SurfaceView{

    public BitmapFactory myBitmapFactory = new BitmapFactory();

    public  Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap;
    public Board(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    //here i implement all the abstract classes, which are not important now

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image), 90, 90, false);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 20, 20, paint);
    }
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap b){
        this.myBitmap = b;
    }
}
```

And I have also my activity class, where after a button click which runs the method `changeImage`. I want two change this image which i put on my canvas

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public Context context = this;
    public Board board;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_game);
    }
    public void changeImage(View view){
        Bitmap tmpBitmap = new Bitmap();
        BitmapFactory tmpBitmapFactory = new BitmapFactory();
        tmpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmpBitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image2), 130, 130, false);
        board.setBitmap(tmpBitmap);
        board.invalidate();
    }
}
```

But after calling method `changeImage` nothing is changing - the image is the same as at the beginning. I tried to use `invalidate()` also inside `setBitmap()` method, but it also doesn't work. Is this because every time when I call `invalidate()` I'm creating a new Bitmap or I'm doing something else wrong?

---EDIT---
So ofc, wrong was that:

```
myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image), 90, 90, false);
```

was setting all the time the same image. I changed it, but still invalidate() thosent work. I mean the image is not changing. I was looking for the result in other topics, but I did't find any solution, now my classes looks like this:

```
  public class Board extends SurfaceView{


       public BitmapFactory myBitmapFactory = new BitmapFactory();
       public  Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image), size, size, false);
    public int tmp = 0;
        public Paint paint = new Paint();
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           Paint paint = new Paint();
           canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 50, 50, paint);
    }
    public void setBitmaps(Bitmap one){
            this.paint = new Paint();
            this.myBitmap = one;
            this.tmp=4;
            this.invalidate();

        }
```

And the method changeImage() inside my activity:

```
public void changeImage(View view){
        Bitmap tmpBitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue), 230, 230, false);
myGameBoard.setBitmaps(tmpBitmap1);

}
```

I tried to use: invalidate(), postInvalidate(), but it doesn't work and i hae now idea what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

You update `myBitmap` in `onDraw()`:

```
myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image), 90, 90, false);
```

So your updated image is still not used as you directly override it with another image...

---

(*old answer, which is now obsolete due to fixed question*)
There seems something else off in your example code. In `setBitmap()` you store the new bitmap in `pawnBitmap`. In the `onDraw()` method, you do not use `pawnBitmap`. So it is expected that nothing changes, as you do not use the changed values...

---

(*old answer, which is now obsolete due to change in question*)
You are trying to call a static class method with:

```
Board.setBitmap(tmpBitmap);
Board.invalidate();
```

(I am wondering why you did not get compile errors... Or did you forgot to mention them?)
As `Board` is the name of your class. Instead you need to call the instance method.

```
Board board = ...
board.setBitmap(tmpBitmap);
board.invalidate();
```

This obviously requires the `board` instance, which you need to available in your activity class.

Note: if you are calling `invalidate()` from a non-UI thread, you need to use [`postInvalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29).

Comment: No, sorry is my mistake ofc I'm calling board.setBitmap .. inside my program, I just write here wrong the name of my instance. This is everything ok in my program. And i don't have any errors, everything seems to be ok, but the image on my canvas is not changing

Comment: Updated my answer with another potential cause/problem with your code.

Comment: Now, it's not this. When I'm put a piece of code I change the names, but sometimes i just forget to change something, sorry. I will improve all the mistakes in code above, and then we will try to find where is the mistake

Comment: `this.Bitmap` does not exists and in the method arguments you pass an array of bitmaps?!

Comment: @Ziva This is getting silly and you are wasting people's time.  Please copy and paste your code, no typos.  If it doesn't compile, then fix it first. The code in your question won't even compile!

Comment: Simon, i think that if i didn't post any information about errors that means it not exist. I don't need to paste all code (like abstract methods, constructor etc) because it's not necceserry and not everyone want to read lines of code which are not important. I think the problem is enought clear explained

Comment: I updated my answer again (for the last time, I do not keep on updating my answer because you question was wrong/changes again). I totally agree with @Simon you code is messy because you are typing it. Next, time please copy/paste the relevant parts to prevent typos.